# MySQL/PHP Error: Input a value with an apostrophe ( ' )

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this particular feature in my program wherein I want it to count all the Malls with value = 2 Robinson's Manila. However, there is an error since the apostrophe is seen by the program as a closing mark for the text.

Here's my code for that particular feature:

```
 <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="GET">
        <select name="formStats">
            <option value="Rob">Robinson's Manila Stores</option>
            <option value="MoA">Mall of Asia Stores</option>
            <option value="GG">Greenbelt/Glorietta Stores</option>
        </select> 

        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    switch ($varStats)
    {   
        case "Rob": $show = "Mall = '2 Robinson's Manila'"; break;
        case "MoA": $show = "Mall = '3 Mall of Asia'"; break;
        case "GG": $show = "Mall = '1 Glorietta/Greenbelt Complex '"; break;
    }
```

I think I need to use the ` mark but I'm not sure with the exact syntax.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the apostrophe "Robinson's" in the assignment to the $show variable in the switch case. You should escape it writing "Robinson\'s"

Comment: it it worked, please, set my answer as a solution for your question :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function to escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.